# jQuery PHP Ajax save multiple selected box based on process

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple select box on my form.

```
<form id="form">
    <?php
    for($i = 1; $i<=9; $i++)
    {
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="modelID" value="1"/>
        <div>
        Process <?php echo $i; ?>
        <select class="process" name="process[]" id="Process<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <option value="">Choose One</option>
            <option value="P1">Process 1</option>
            <option value="P2">Process 2</option>
            <option value="P3">Process 3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
</form>
```

And now I need to get the value of each value for select box that only filled to PHP.

Example I only choose Process 2, then store it to PHP to be `Process 2: P2`.

And on the PHP I need to save it to table.

```
//maybe using foreach?
$insert = oci_parse($c1, "INSERT INTO tbl_process(MODELID, PROCESS1, PROCESS2, PROCESS3) VALUES('1', '', '', '')");
//ONLY insert filled select box, on my example PROCESS2 will be filled P2 to table column.
```

And the JS

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function()
{
    var modelID = $("#modelID").val();
    var form_data = $("#form").serialize();

    alert(form_data);

    $.ajax(
    {
        'type': 'post',
        'url': 'saveProcess',
        'data': {
            'form_data': form_data
        },
        'success': function(response)
        {

        }
    });
});
```

My question, how to ONLY insert filled select box, on my example PROCESS2 will be filled P2 to table column?

Comment: What do you mean by _"only insert filled select box"_? All of them would be "filled" since you don't have any empty default value`?

Comment: Also, `$("#modelID")` wouldn't return anything since there's no element with that ID. You will have 10 inputs with the _name_ `modelID` though.

Comment: Also it's not multi select based in your code. It's missing `multiple` attribute.

Comment: As per your code. If you click on submit button then P1 will go as default value for non selected filed. So please add `<option value="">please select</option>` in loop to send default field.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry, I just updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is only pass the modelID and processID using the ajax call.
Whenever the user changes the process you save the data through the ajax call.

```
<form id="form">
  <?php for($i = 1; $i<=9; $i++) { ?>
    Process <?php echo $i; ?>
    <select class="process" modelID="<?php echo $i; ?>">
      <option value="P1">Process 1</option>
      <option value="P2">Process 2</option>
      <option value="P3">Process 3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  <?php } ?>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.process').change(function(){
    var modelID = $(this).attr('modelID');
    var processID = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'saveProcess.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'modelID':modelID, 'processID':processID},
      success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
          console.log( errorThrown );
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```